# Having a problem installing Newsapi on Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I have installed the NewsApi via my Mac OS terminal using `pip3 install newsapi-python`, and when I check my anaconda environment packages I see newsapi installed. However when I try to use the following command I get an error:

`from newsapi import NewsApiClient`

error:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'NewsApiClient' from 'newsapi' (/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/newsapi/__init__.py)`

Has anybody else experienced this?

Comment: Just install, as Mouhamed has wrote try: pip install newsapi-python

Answer (score 2):

If you have saved your python filename as "news-api.py" or the same as the package name you might face this error. Try renaming your file.

Comment: But the error shows the `site-packages` path so it is not taking a local file instead...

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30157448)

Answer (score 1):

Try this command in main django folder:

```
pip install newsapi-python
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Installing newsapi

1. **upgrade pip version**

```
    pip install --upgrade pip
```

2. **installing newsapi using command prompt**

```
    pip install newsapi-python
```